# display an image pulled from sharepoint using xslt

Tags: sharepoint, xslt

How can I display an image pulled from sharepoint using xslt?

the xml produces a tag 
and its value is:

```
<img alt="" border="0" src="/SiteCollectionImages/Blue%20hills.jpg ....etc
```

but the output is the text above and not the image itself.

the xslt is just:

Rollup-Image: `<xsl:value-of select="Rollup-Image" />`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think this should do the trick

```
<xsl:value-of select="Rollup-Image" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
```